# Washing machine shut off valve leaks

Tags: plumbing

Washing machine shut off leaks. I want to change the shut off.

I traced the hot water line back to the hot water heater. Do I turn water off at hot water heater?

Answer (score 4):

That will probably be the only place with another shut off.

People usually too cheap and lazy to put shut off valves all over the place.

Turn off the outlet valve for hot water tank open hot water faucets near the washing machine or start the fill for washing machine, to reduce pressure in the line.  have a bucket and towels/rags handy and change the valve.

Comment: The water heaters in the places I've lived have shutoff valves for the water heater cold water inlet, but not on the hot water outlet. It's important to turn off the water heater before shutting off its water inlet valve.

Comment: As an option, get everyone out of the house to ensure no water is used, then do the work with the heater on (but the cold water inlet valve still turned off). ;)